# Is It Possible To Use Heroku Scheduler To Automatically Generate A New Blog Post Everyday?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm making a blog like application which I want to automatically generate a new post every day, starting from a user-defined start-date. So for example, if I set it to the 25th of June, from that day and every day afterward it would start generating posts. These automatically generated posts would then be able to be edited by the user.

I've heard of other gems such as Whenever and Rufus-Scheduler which could potentially do this but I've also heard they have issues when deployed to Heroku. Would the Heroku Scheduler be able to automatically generate a new blog post for a user?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(Ruby on Rails) Which Gem to Automatically Generate A New "Blog Post" Every Day?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43713880/ruby-on-rails-which-gem-to-automatically-generate-a-new-blog-post-every-day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Heroku scheduler can do that. I recommend you create a rake task that creates a blog post, e.g.:

```
STARTING_DATE = Date.new(2017, 6, 25)

task :create_post => :environment do
  Post.create!(title: "Draft created on #{Date.today.strftime('%d %b %Y')") if Date.today >= STARTING_DATE
end
```

Then just create a scheduler entry that runs `rake create_post` every day.