# (Ruby on Rails) Which Gem to Automatically Generate A New "Blog Post" Every Day?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making a blog application and want my application to automatically generate a new blog post every day, starting from a user-defined start date. I've heard of a few gems like Clockwork, Whenever, Rufus-Scheduler and I'm not sure which is the best to do this, or if any of them even can.

Has anyone had experience with using any of these gems for something like this? I'm feeling very confused at the moment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any gem as such that will **generate/create** a post for your user. You have to write your own script for creating posts and the scheduler/or other gems you mentioned above will just help you run that script in the form of rake task at regular intervals of your choice.